# How do I convert a Vert.x Future.compose() to an equivalent RxJava2 implementation

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

I have a segment of code which looks like:

```
this.initConfigRetriever()                // Produces Future<JsonObject>
    .compose(this::asyncLoadDbSchema)     // Consumes JsonObject, produces Future<Void>
    .compose(v -> this.provisionRouter()) // Produces Future<RouterFactory>
    .compose(this::createHttpServer)      // Consumes RouterFactory
    .compose(s -> startFuture.complete(), startFuture);
```

And I would like to know how I can convert that into something equivalent in RxJava2? Ideally, I would like something like what Completable does, but with values passed from one to the next:

For example:

```
this.initConfigRetriever()            // Returns a JsonObject
    .andThen(this::asyncLoadDbSchema) // Consumes JsonObject and produces a Void
    .andThen(this::provisionRouter)   // Consume Void and produces RouterFactory
    .andThen(this::createHttpServer)  // Consumes RouterFactory
    .onError(startFuture::fail)       // Consumes any errors along the chain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what my structure finally ended up looking like

```
this.initConfigRetriever()             // If it fails, jump to error handler
    .flatMap(this::asyncLoadDbSchema)  // If it fails, jump to error handler
    .flatMap(this::provisionRouter)    // If it fails, jump to error handler
    .flatMap(this::createHttpServer)   // If it fails, jump to error handler
    .doOnError(startFuture::fail)
    .subscribe(m -> startFuture.complete()); // If all steps succeeded
```

The way that I accomplished this is that each of the methods being flatMapped return `Maybe<T>`. This solved my problem pretty cleanly.

An interesting negative side to this is that when I was debugging to figure this out it was quite difficult to figure out where things were going wrong (I had never started consuming the stream). In order to make this easier to debug in IntelliJ, I converted the method references to lambdas so that I could set breakpoints inside of the lambdas.

For details, you can see the code [HERE](https://github.com/InfoSec812/rhoar-vertx/blob/rxjava-experiment/adjective/src/main/java/com/redhat/labs/adjective/MainVerticle.java#L49)

Answer (score 1):

below might be along the lines of what you're looking for.

- the `flatMap` operator allows you to pass values from one stream into the creation of another
- errors can be handled by the subscriber
- i've used `Single` off the assumption that this appears to be related to bootstrapping logic that runs once

  ```
  // Produces Future<JsonObject>
  Single.just("...")
          .flatMapCompletable {
              // Consumes JsonObject, emits "completion" (or ends the stream)
              Completable.fromCallable { /* ... */ }
          }
          .toSingle {
              // On complete produces RouterFactory
              Single.just("...")
          }
          .flatMapCompletable {
              // Consumes RouterFactory, emits "completion" (or ends the stream)
              Completable.fromCallable { /* ... */ }
          }
          .subscribeBy(
                  onComplete = { 
                      // Handle completion...
                  },
                  onError = { error -> 
                      // Handle errors... 
                  }
          )
  ```

i hope that helps!

Comment: I ended up with something similar, except I had the methods return the appropriate types so that it is more readable. See answer below.